# Rails: How to make "button_to" button to appear on the sameline (without a newline)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3, view

I have a block iterator to display a user and a related action to be displayed on the same line for every iteration.

You can visualize it like this:

```
user1  update_attribute_button
user2  update_attribute_button.
...
and so on.
```

If I use a `button_to` method the button is getting displayed on a newline. which I don't want.

Here is my code snippet:

```
<% @post.bids.each do |bid| %>
  <p>
    <%= bid.user.email %>   
    <%= button_to "Offer Bid", offer_bid_post_bid_path(@post, bid), :action => "offer_bid">
  </p>
<% end %>
```

But with the above code the 'email' and 'offer bid' appear on two separate lines, but I want to display them both on the same line.

If I use `link_to` instead of `button_to` I'm able to achieve my idea, but not able to do it with a button_to. What is the difference between `link_to` and `button_to`?
I want to display the 'offer bid' as a button only.
How do I make the button_to button appear on the same line as the 'email'?

Please let me know if the question's description is not clear.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A button_to generates a form and a div around the button. So, if you do not restrict the width of the container which is before the button, it will take 100% of the width pushing the button down.

```
<% @post.bids.each do |bid| %>
  <p>
    <div style="float: left; width: auto;"><%= bid.user.email %></div>   
    <%= button_to "Offer Bid", offer_bid_post_bid_path(@post, bid), :action => "offer_bid" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5):

`button_to` renders to a form tag, so I just altered the CSS to ensure the form tag doesn't create a new line.

But to apply it only to a specific form tag then give add `form_class: "myButton"` see below.

In your something.html.erb

```
<%= button_to "Offer Bid", offer_bid_post_bid_path(@post, bid), :action => "offer_bid", form_class: "myButton">
```

Put this in your `application.css`

```
myButton {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm! As of Rails 6.1, the default class for the form tag for `button_to` is named `button_to`. So, unless you want to completely overwrite the default CSS, `form_class: "inline_form button_to"` would be better. BTW, the closing double-quotation is missing in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is not to do with rails but rather how web browser's render forms.

A button_to is just a convenient way to create a form with a non-visible field. If you want the form on the same row as the email address you'll need to put it into a container, most usually a div, set the div to float left and overflow hidden.